# WKWebView full page screenshot

Tags: ios, swift, ios11, wkwebview

I'm trying to make a screenshot of full webpage rendered in WKWebView:

```
    let snapshotConfiguration = WKSnapshotConfiguration()
    snapshotConfiguration.snapshotWidth = 1440

    webView.takeSnapshot(with: snapshotConfiguration) { (image, error) in
        UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image!, nil, nil, nil)
    }
```

But method `takeSnapshot` creates only screenshot of viewport.

How can I make screenshot of full webpage?

Answer (score 1):

You need to stitch the images together.  You can get the Webview contentSize using javascript:

```
webView.evaluateJavaScript("document.body.scrollHeight", completionHandler: { [weak self] (height, error) in
    self?.webViewContentHeight = (height as? CGFloat) ?? -1
})
```

You can use a UIGraphicsImageRenderer to to create an image context of that size then render each page of the web view in the image context:

```
let image = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: CGSize(width: webview.bounds.size.width, height: webViewContentHeight)).image { [webview] context in
    for offset in stride(from: 0, to: Int(webViewContentHeight), by: Int(webview.bounds.size.height)) {
        let drawPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: CGFloat(offset))
        webview.scrollView.contentOffset = drawPoint
        webview.drawHierarchy(in: CGRect.init(origin: drawPoint, size: webview.bounds.size), afterScreenUpdates: true)
    }
}
```

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/kodrim5z5h7pjjp/IMG_0024.JPG?dl=0
the height is correct but part of screenshot is empty

Answer (score 0):

I was able to capture full screen by changing the frame of the WKWebView.
Answered here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/69144931/851258